# Suggested Retag/Synonym: WebSphere MQ is now IBM MQ

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

IBM's WebSphere MQ product (formerly MQSeries) has been renamed to IBM MQ. I think we should retag the [websphere-mq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/websphere-mq) as [ibm-mq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-mq)

At that point both [websphere-mq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/websphere-mq) and [mqseries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mqseries) should be synonyms of [ibm-mq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-mq).

Note that the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/websphere-mq/info) for [websphere-mq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/websphere-mq) contains a detailed version history noting the naming changes over the years.  Creation of [websphere-mq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/websphere-mq) here helped nudge practitioners toward use of the new brand name instead of [mqseries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mqseries).

The [ibm-mq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-mq) synonym was created more of functional necessity to differentiate between IBM's product versus Zero MQ, ActiveMQ, MSMQ, etc.  However, now that it is the official brand name is is hoped that this tag/synonym swap will again nudge practitioners toward the new branding, thus helping them discover all the new documentation, downloads and community available under the new brand that might otherwise be overlooked.

Comment: This just in: tech companies have a perverse fascination with renaming technologies.

Comment: looks like something already happened: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/websphere-mq/synonyms ? But it doesn't look like that is what you hoped for?

Comment: Back when we mapped [tag:ibm-mq] to [tag:websphere-mq] the product name actually *was* WebSphere MQ and the tag [tag:ibm-mq] was descriptive.  Now that IBM has made it the actual product name what was just descriptive up to now has become canonical.

Comment: There was a song that went: round and round and round and round... seems to fit this situation.

Comment: Structurally, no. When we created [tag:ibm-mq] it was a simple synonym add. No remapping work was required then so no duplicate effort being asked here. Over the product's life the SO tag has tended to reflect the official name, despite a lag after each IBM rebranding. Superficially maybe, but even that's a stretch.  The name has been a linear progression MQSeries to WebSphere MQ to IBM MQ.  The ask here is merely that the SO tags keep pace which, if I understand it, serves SO's stated mission better than not changing it, esp for new users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now done;

[image]

Unfortunately I made a mess  of the entire process, and lost the revision history of the tag wiki (well, I lost the entire tag wiki for a short while, but eventually [restored the latest revision from data.SE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/602571#resultSets)).

In future, I must remember to ensure the desired target tag exists before adding (or reversing) a synonym. Oops.

---

Anyway, I've had a go at updating the tag wiki (and excerpt) so that "ibm-mq" is used primarily now, rather than "websphere-mq", but you may way to give it a read through to check I didn't mess *that* up as well....

Comment: Thanks!  I will review and make any further corrections.  It's a low-traffic tag so we *really* appreciate the work on behalf of our little SO community in there.

Comment: I don't know how much work it entails and nobody has commented on it yet, but all the stats were lost in the retag.  At this point I'm thinking it's a "nice to have" if we can get them back, but am not aware of any plans to storm the castle with pitchforks and torches over it.  In any case, thanks for the work in getting it retagged regardless of the stats outcome.

Comment: @T.Rob: this should be because the stats are still attributed to [tag:websphere-mq], rather than [tag:ibm-mq]. This will be fixed by me merging the tags together (i.e. all websphere-mq tags on questions will be re-written to ibm-mq, but I'm not sure if that makes sense for all the historical questions?

Comment: The main thing is whether we retain tag-specific privileges.  Being a low-traffic tag set, it took forever before we got a core group with sufficient privileges to properly curate the tag.  I'd hate to have to start over.  On the other hand, close/reopen isn't a frequently used privilege here so I'm not sure if/how much it hurts us.  I'm just shy of the 25k needed to look at stats so just guessing here.

Comment: In other words, this: http://i.imgur.com/pSi8oJu.jpg Note the lack of any ibm-mq badges.

Comment: @T.Rob: I've just merged the tags. Within the next 24 hours (with the help of a few background processes), those badges you highlighted will be lost for websphere-mq, and regained for ibm-mq. You'll also regain the mjolnir ability for ibm-mq questions. The reason I didn't initially perform the merge was because I thought legacy questions would make more sense tagged with websphere-mq, rather than ibm-mq... however I think the need for tag-specific privileges outweigh this, so the merge I've just done should solve that.

Comment: Thanks!  Merging them would seem to be the right answer in a product context as well.  We still have people referring to it at MQSeries and that's been well over a decade now. They have trouble finding recent info with that keyword. Meanwhile new users generally don't know the history and can be confused by the naming changes.  Consolidating all the history into one place makes it more obvious both to really old-timers and to new product users that it's all the same product.  I'll go look up "mjolnir" now.  :-)

Comment: Seems to be perfect now.  Tag history restored and editing privileges regained.  Thanks!