# Problematic SO synonym: [ibm] -> [websphere]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, synonym-removal-request

I am looking for some advice or moderator action to help with a problematic tag on SO, [ibm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm) -> [websphere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/websphere)

Context:

- "IBM" is a corporation with hundreds/thousands of software products.
- "WebSphere" is a shorthand for a family of about a half-dozen Java application server products sold by IBM.

For some time, we [websphere] folks have seen a surprising amount of questions about other IBM products—some very far removed from us.  A cleaver colleague just realized the culprit, and there is an approved synonym from "ibm" to "websphere".

"ibm" itself is kind of a useless tag, but narrowing it to "websphere" is really acutely wrong and makes it painful to monitor "websphere".

I do not see any way to propose to break the synonym link. Is there someone who can help or give a hint?

CC @samuel-liew as a synonym proposer.

Comment: A cleaver colleague sounds awesome.

Comment: Related: *[Suggested Retag/Synonym: WebSphere MQ is now IBM MQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339525)* and *[Burninate request for tag: webshperemq](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342456)*

Answer (score 8):

I've removed the synonym.

At time time of the removal, there were no questions left with the [ibm] tag (presumably merged when the synonym was made?), so the [ibm] tag is still gone.

This does also mean that any mistagged questions (if any) need to be manually cleaned up. There's no rush to do so to be clear, but it isn't happening on its own. The synonym tool said there were over 1100 renames, but this may not be indicative of anything wrt. the current state of the tag aside, as you've already observed, [websphere] turning into a prime target for incorrectly tagged questions about other IBM products.

It might be worth blacklisting [ibm] (in the same chain as [microsoft/apple](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284167/6296561), [godaddy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/331817/6296561), and more that I know exist but can't trivially dig up; this is left as an exercise to the interested reader), but that's a separate request for Later™

---

In general, as far as I'm aware, only mods (or obviously staff, but they tend not to get involved in stuff like this) can "undo" a synonym.

I say "undo" because we don't actually undo it. We have an option to delete the synonym, but not to fully undo it; i.e. revert any renames. There's a whole bunch of asterisks and edge-cases here as well, though they're not important (and they're probably documented somewhere already) and mostly just mean a cleanup following the removal may be necessary.

Anyway, meta (because this was migrated from MSE, specifically the relevant child meta; for Stack Overflow, that means this meta) is the place to request a synonym removal. Posting here was the right thing to do